# Identifying objects in tensorflowjs using custom keras models

Tags: javascript, python, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I want to use a tensorflow model in javascript for real-time object detection.
For that, I am following this tutorial by tensorflow.org: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras
I have trained model in keras, exported the model to a .h5 format, converted it to a json file and finally imported the model.

Here’s a snippet of my javascript code block,

```
net = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://localhost:8000/converted/model.json');
const imgEl = document.getElementById('img');
const t = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgEl)
let result = await net.predict(t)
```

The image I am trying to identify is 255 x 255 , RGB
I get error that the input image is 3 dimensional but the expected was 4.
I have attached the snipped of the error.
[error in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYFG.png)

I have tried re-shaping the input image but to no avail. Can someone help?

Comment: I am not well versed in TF. My previous comment was slightly wrong - it appears to me, that batchsize comes first, not last, so i currently would guess a shape of `[1, 255, 255, 3]` to work. Also note, that in your error screenshot, it describes `[225, 225, 3]`, which is again different to your question text.

Comment: could you kindly also show your model network in Tensorflow.js using `model.summary()`. I suspect too that the network needs a batchsize as well.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I am sorry, the image I am using is 225 X 225 and not 255 X 255. 
I am quite sure I need to reshape the image before I run prediction. I just don't know how/ what to do.